# fake DataRepository - emulating the database

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, repository, rhino-mocks

Quick Info: I'm using C# 4.0 and RhinoMocks (with AAA)

I'll explain with some code what I'm thinking about doing:

```
public class SampleData
{
    private List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>()
    {
         new Person { PersonID = 1, Name = "Jack"},
         new Person { PersonID = 2, Name = "John"}
    };

    public List<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
    }
}
```

So this is a class which mimics data in the DB. Now I want to use this data in my unit tests. In other words, instead of getting data out of the DB, I want to get them out of the datarepository.

I think I can achieve this by stubbing the Repository and by making it use the DataRepository instead:

```
UC1003_ConsultantsBeherenBL consultantsBeherenBL = new UC1003_ConsultantsBeherenBL();

consultantsBeherenBL = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<UC1003_ConsultantsBeherenBL>();
consultantsBeherenBL.Repository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository>();
```

This would cause my code to automaticly look for data in the DataRepository instead. So instead of stubbing a method and directly inserting a list (e.g. d => d.Find(Arg.Is.Anything)).IgnoreArguments().Return(a list which you just filled up)) I'd get "real" data back (the data which has been filtered from the DataRepository). This means I can test if my code can really find something, without having to insert test data in my DB (integration test).

How would I go about implementing such a thing? I've tried looking on the web for articles or questions, but I can't seem to find a lot :/

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've tried to SimpleInjector and StructureMap, but I'm stuck implementing one of them.

I'm currently using a repository on my entity framework, so my baseBL looks like this (note:  all my other BL's enherit from this one):

```
public class BaseBL
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public IRepository Repository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_repository == null)
                _repository = new Repository(new DetacheringenEntities());
            return _repository;
        }
        set { _repository = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
    ... --> Generic methods
```

My Repository class:

```
public class Repository : BaseRepository, IRepository
{
    #region Base Implementation

    private bool _disposed;

    public Repository(DetacheringenEntities context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._contextReused = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IRepository Members

    public int Add<T>(T entity)
    ... --> implementations of generic methods
```

As far as I can make out, I now need to be able to say in my tests that instead of using the DetacheringenEntities, I need to use my DataRepository. I don't understand how I switch out my entity framework with a data class, because that data class won't fit in there.

Should I let my DataRepository enherit my IRepository class and make my own implementations?

```
public class SampleData : IRepository
```

But I can't do things like this with my lists :/

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        return Repository.GetAll<T>();
    }
```

Big thanks again for help

**EDIT:** I realised that a unit test doesn't need a data repository, so I'm just testing that logic in an integration test. This makes a data repository useless, since the code can be tested without a repository.
I'd like to thank everybody for their help though, thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84).

Comment: Well, this isn't just for one test, it's something I want to set up so I can run multiple tests on, and it wont pulute my DB. In this case, I want to test a search function, where I've multiple people in my FakeDataRepository. When I call the methode that needs to be tested, I want the methode to use the FakeDataRepository as the source, so it can filter out the correct Persons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Dependency injection framework](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) to handle your dependencies. In your unit test you can swap the real implementation with a stubbed one.

In StructureMap for example, you'll say in your code. "All right, now give me the active instance of `IDataRepository`", for your normal code this would point to an implementation to the real database. In your unittest you can then overwrite this by putting `ObjectFactory.Inject(new FakeDataRepository())`. The fake repo is then used by all your code, which makes it really easy to test a single unit of work.Í

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm going to try to implement it (in 4.0). I'll let you know if it worked, because it sure sounds like the thing I need :)

Comment: I've added a new section in my question, because I've some problems implementing it.